# Use loop to replace word and run multiple lines

Tags: r, loops

I have the word "JAN" in many lines. Here is an example:

`OccRateJAN_Yuki<-YukiJANoccupied/31`

I want to use loop so that each time "JAN" is in a line, replace it with "FEB" and run the whole thing. Then change every "JAN" to "MAR" and run the whole thing... Until "DEC" and then end the statement.

Is it possible to search for the word "JAN" through all the lines of code, replace the word and run? How could I write the code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? It's worth noting that R has a built-in constant called "month.abb" which contains the values "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / etc which might help you with your task, e.g. `print(toupper(month.abb))`

Comment: What do you mean by 'run the whole thing'? R works on vector simultaneously e. g. For adding say 2 to each of the element 1:10 you need not create loop just 1:10 + 2 will do the job

Answer (score 1):

If you're running an R script from bash, you can loop over it with:

```
array=(JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC)
for f in {0..11}
  do sed "s/JAN/"${array[f]}"/g" script.R > script_"$f".R
  Rscript --vanilla script_"$f".R
done
```

This keeps each individual script (one per month named script_0.R / script_1.R / etc) in case a run fails and you need to rerun it.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am running from R Markdown. Could you explain how could I do it from R Markdown please?